# navigation bar and button

Tags: iphone

any ideas how i can click on a button and then direct me back to homepage without having the navigation bar to show the previous page? meaning it's like starting from the beginning of the home page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking what I think you're asking (poping view controllers to the root view controller of a navigation controller's stack) then I believe you are looking for

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```